# Create an API route to write in Google sheet with Node js

Tags: node.js, api, express, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to create an API route /api/append to write inside a google sheet using their Google APIs and the code below, I couldn't get it right, I need to pass the values that will be appended in the sheet to the DoAppend function via POST method for example.

But I couldn't manipulate the "auth" parameter in the function :  DoAppend(auth), it's the global Oauth variable to use the google APIs. (the functions is at the end of the code).

Here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];


const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';



fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {

  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);

  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.

  authorize(JSON.parse(content), DoAppend);

});



/**

 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the

 * given callback function.

 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.

 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.

 */

function authorize(credentials, callback) {

  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;

  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(

      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);



  // Check if we have previously stored a token.

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {

    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);

    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));

    callback(oAuth2Client);

  });

}



/**

 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then

 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.

 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.

 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.

 */

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {

  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({

    access_type: 'offline',

    scope: SCOPES,

  });

  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({

    input: process.stdin,

    output: process.stdout,

  });

  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {

    rl.close();

    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {

      if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);

      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);

      // Store the token to disk for later program executions

      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {

        if (err) return console.error(err);

        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);

      });

      callback(oAuth2Client);

    });

  });

}



/**

 * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:

 * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Qezk7i2fUz24ldDR_pbPUptliLwzmu-t0fFyOgYm00/edit#gid=123987456

 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.

 */

function DoAppend(auth) {

  const sheets0 = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});

  sheets0.spreadsheets.values.append({
    spreadsheetId: 'ID here',
    range: 'Testing',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    resource: {
      values: [
        [new Date().toISOString(), "Some value", "Another value"]
      ],
    },
    auth: auth
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
  })

}
```

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more depth where you are stuck?

Comment: I want to create a POST route to pass the "values" input in the DoAppend for example :

Comment: /api/append with body paylaod : {date, name, lastname} , but I can't manipulate the auth parameter in the DoAppend function (it's the Oauth variable) to use the google API.

Comment: Could you mention the auth thing in your question? I don't think you mentioned it in the description.

Comment: Done, I edited my question

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append
You can use something like this in you own function

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?